# rename multiple files in a folder using R

Tags: r, file, rename

I have a folder which contains several files named by the date the data was measured. For example: "07182014.csv","07192014.csv"...

Since I have multiple stations for the measurements, I would like to add the station number before each file name for distinguish purposes. For example, the file "07182014.csv" will become "N1_07182014.csv".

I'm new to R, and most of the time I search the web for solutions to my data analysis problem.

Can someone help me revise the code I'm having below so I can properly rename all files in the folder? Or if any other better solution can be provided, that will be helpful!

```
setwd("C:\\data")
files <- list.files() 
sapply(files,FUN=function(eachPath){ 
file.rename(from=eachPath,to=sub(pattern="[$.csv]", paste0("N0_"),eachPath)) 
})
```

Thanks a lot！

Comment: I would have though the sub call would be: `sub(pattern="(.*)(\\\.csv)", "N0_\\1\\2"), eachPath)`

Comment: why not simply `file.rename(f, paste0('N1_', f))`?

Comment: Right and fix the files/filez error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my answer:

```
folder = "C:\\data"
files <- list.files(folder,pattern = "*.CSV",full.names = T) 
   sapply(files,FUN=function(eachPath){ 
   file.rename(from=eachPath,to= sub(pattern="\\/", paste0("\\/N0_"),eachPath))
 })
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But nothing changed for the file name with your code.

Comment: It is working on my computer. 
do you have *.csv files in "c:\data",
Are they all small letter? if not change csv to CSV

Comment: Thanks. My files are in .CSV and I changed the code. But the output I got is: C:/data/07182014.CSV C:/data/07212014.CSV 
            FALSE                          FALSE

Comment: I changed the code. This one should really work.

Comment: Thanks, the updated code works! But is there any way to put "N0_" before the dates in the file name? Like "N0_07182014.csv" instead of current output of "07182014_N0.csv"?

Comment: yes. it is possible use the following code:

   folder = "C:\\data"
   files <- list.files(folder,pattern = "*.CSV",full.names = T) 
   sapply(files,FUN=function(eachPath){ 
   file.rename(from=eachPath,to= sub(pattern="\\/", paste0("\\/N0_"),eachPath)) 
})

Comment: updated accordingly. use the updated code.

Comment: The updated code did nothing to rename the files correctly... I noticed “\\/" in the code, is this correct?

Comment: It is working on my computer! :|
did you defined folder = "C:\\data"? 
don't use "/" in folder defination!

Comment: Oh, R has so many tricks!!! Thanks so much for the code!