# R: massive file rename in specific directory to four-digit format

Tags: r, rename

Let's have a list of images:

```
destination <- "C:/Users/uzytkownik/Pictures/image/"
myfiles_jpg <- list.files(path = destination, pattern = "jpg",  full.names = TRUE)
### let's see
head(myfiles_jpg)
[1] "C:/Users/uzytkownik/Pictures/image/1.jpg"    "C:/Users/uzytkownik/Pictures/image/10.jpg"  
[3] "C:/Users/uzytkownik/Pictures/image/100.jpg"  "C:/Users/uzytkownik/Pictures/image/1000.jpg"
[5] "C:/Users/uzytkownik/Pictures/image/1001.jpg" "C:/Users/uzytkownik/Pictures/image/1002.jpg"
### How many?
length(myfiles_jpg)
[1] 2920
```

I want to convert names of the images to four-digit format, for instance

```
"C:/Users/uzytkownik/Pictures/image/1.jpg"
```

to

```
"C:/Users/uzytkownik/Pictures/image/0001.jpg"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example we will use the filenames in a list:

```
library(stringr)

myfiles <- list("C:/Users/uzytkownik/Pictures/image/1.jpg","C:/Users/uzytkownik/Pictures/image/100.jpg","C:/Users/uzytkownik/Pictures/image/1001.jpg")

myfiles_new <- list()

for(i in 1:length(myfiles)){
  index <- regmatches(myfiles[[i]], gregexpr("(?<=image\\/)[0-9]+", myfiles[i], perl=TRUE))
  replacement <- str_pad(string = index, width = 4, side = "left", pad = 0)
  myfiles_new[[i]] <- sub('(?<=image\\/)[0-9]+', replacement, myfiles[i], perl = TRUE)
}

myfiles_new
[[1]]
[1] "C:/Users/uzytkownik/Pictures/image/0001.jpg"

[[2]]
[1] "C:/Users/uzytkownik/Pictures/image/0100.jpg"

[[3]]
[1] "C:/Users/uzytkownik/Pictures/image/1001.jpg"
```

Then using somthing similar to what was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25673643/rename-multiple-files-in-a-folder-using-r) we should be able to rename the files:

```
sapply(myfiles_jpg,FUN=function(eachPath){ 
file.rename(from=eachPath,to=myfiles_new, eachPath))
})
```

Comment: And finally: for(i in 1:length(myfiles)){
  file.rename(myfiles[i], myfiles_new[[i]])
}

Comment: @Mikołaj feel free to add your comment to the existing answer which is a community answer.